# Check rows for same entries in neighbouring columns (part 2)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need a select command to do the following:

I have a table like this

```
TIMESTAMP |    ID | col1 | col2 | ...

t         |    23 | AAA  |  BBB | ...
t         |    23 | BBB  |  AAA | ...
t         |    59 | asf  |  567 | ...
t         |    02 | XXX  |  ZZZ | ...
t         |    02 | YYY  |  XXX | ...

t-1       |    23 | AAA  |  BBB | ...
t-1       |    23 | BBB  |  AAA | ...
t-1       |    59 | asf  |  567 | ...
t-1       |    02 | XXX  |  ZZZ | ...
t-1       |    02 | YYY  |  XXX | ...

t-2       |    .. | ...  |  ... | ...
t-2       |    .. | ...  |  ... | ...
```

For each time there are sometimes 2 rows with the same ID. Now I want to select the most recent ones (only with timestamp = t), which have also the same diametrical neighbouring entries in two specific columns (here col1, col2) like the first two rows at the example. And by analogy this ones, which have the same ID but different entries (see last two rows) .

As a result for the example I want to have two selects:

```
TIMESTAMP |   ID  | col1 | col2 | ...
t         |   23  | AAA  |  BBB | ...
t         |   23  | BBB  |  AAA | ...
```

and

```
TIMESTAMP |   ID  | col1 | col2 | ...
t         |   02  | XXX  |  ZZZ | ...
t         |   02  | YYY  |  XXX | ...
```

I know that it should work with this

```
SELECT a.id, a.col1, a.col2
  FROM tbl AS a
  JOIN tbl AS b ON 
      (     a.id=b.id
        AND (a.col1 =  b.col2 OR  a.col2 = b.col1)
        AND (a.col1 != b.col1 AND a.col2 != b.col2)
      )
```

but I dont know how to select only the newest entries...

Comment: what do you mean by newest? Todays entries, last 3 hours, or ..?

Comment: this ones with the maximal timestamp, i think it should be like this: TIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM tbl)

Comment: That seems correct, did it work?

Comment: i am not sure, because i dont know hot to combine these two statements correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Your query so far needs a `DISTINCT` in it as well as the latest timestamp predicate:

```
select distinct ta.*
from tbl ta
  JOIN tbl AS tb ON 
      (     ta.id=tb.id
        AND (ta.col1 =  tb.col2 OR  ta.col2 = tb.col1)
        AND (ta.col1 != tb.col1 AND ta.col2 != tb.col2)
      )
inner join (
  SELECT a.id,max(a.`timestamp`) as maxTimestamp
  FROM tbl AS a
  JOIN tbl AS b ON 
      (     a.id=b.id
        AND (a.col1 =  b.col2 OR  a.col2 = b.col1)
        AND (a.col1 != b.col1 AND a.col2 != b.col2)
      )
  GROUP by a.id
) b on b.id = ta.id and b.maxTimestamp = ta.`timestamp`;
```

Comment: unfortunetely this is not working, why did you put timestamp in '...'? Is there any meaning behind?